# p4 changes ignore certain directories and files due to maxscanrows

Tags: unix, perforce, perforce-client-spec

When I run `p4 changes ...` in a particular directory I am getting the following error:

`Too many rows scanned (over 16000000); see 'p4 help maxscanrows'.`

I have figured out which directory is causing the issues, but now I don't know how to exclude it from my `p4 changes ...` command.

I have tried several variations with no success:

```
p4 changes ... -//depot/.../baddir/...
p4 changes ... -baddir/...
```

Is this even possible with a single `p4 changes` command?

Below is a simple example of what I am trying to do:

I have some directories and files:

```
base/
    sub0/
    sub1/
    sub2/
    file0.txt
    file1.txt
    file2.txt
```

I want to run `p4 changes ...` in `base` and have it include `sub0` and `sub1` along with all files within `base` but exclude `sub2`.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple arguments to a command aren't combined into a single mapping, they're evaluated independently, so exclusions don't do anything when they're specified on the command line.  Instead, add those exclusions to your client view:

```
//depot/base/... //your_client/...
-//depot/base/sub2/... //your_client/sub2/...
```

If removing the directory from your client view is infeasible because you need to work with these files, your MaxScanRows limit should be set higher -- the idea of MaxScanResults and MaxScanRows is to force you to limit your client view and/or queries to include only the files/revisions that are necessary for your project.  If your project actually contains more files than that, the limits are set too low.